# How to scrape pages with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I want to scrape one site by Selenium, total there are 10 pages. My code as below, but why I only can get the first-page result:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector


MAX_PAGE_NUM = 10
MAX_PAGE_DIG = 3

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\zhang\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Buyer, Price \n")

for i in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM + 1):
    page_num = (MAX_PAGE_DIG - len(str(i))) * "0" + str(i)
    url = "https://www.oilandgasnewsworldwide.com/Directory1/DREQ/Drilling_Equipment_Suppliers_?page=" + page_num

    driver.get(url)

    names = sel.xpath('//*[@class="fontsubsection nomarginpadding lmargin opensans"]/text()').extract()
    Countries = sel.xpath('//td[text()="Country:"]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract()
    websites = sel.xpath('//td[text()="Website:"]/following-sibling::td/a/@href').extract()

driver.close()
print(len(names), len(Countries), len(websites))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here first I get the names, Countries and websites of each page with `find_elements_by_xpath` and they are stored into a list. The text is extracted of each elemnt in the list and the value is added to a new list.

```
from selenium import webdriver

MAX_PAGE_NUM = 10

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users...\\chromedriver.exe')

names_list = list()
Countries_list = list()
websites_list = list()

# The for loop is to get each of the 10 pages
for i in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM):
    page_num = str(i)
    url = "https://www.oilandgasnewsworldwide.com/Directory1/DREQ/Drilling_Equipment_Suppliers_?page=" + page_num

    driver.get(url)

    # Use "driver.find_elements" instead of "driver.find_element" to get all of them. You get a list of WebElements of each page
    names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='fontsubsection nomarginpadding lmargin opensans']")

    # To get the value of each WebElement in the list. You have to iterate on the list 
    for i in range(0, len(names)):
    # Now you add each value into a new list 
        names_list.append(names[i].text)


    Countries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[text()='Country:']/following-sibling::td")
    for i in range(0, len(Countries)):
        Countries_list.append(Countries[i].text)

    websites = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[text()='Website:']/following-sibling::td")
    for i in range(0, len(websites)):
        websites_list.append(websites[i].text)

print(names_list)
print(Countries_list)               
print(websites_list)

driver.close()
```

I hope this works for you

**Option:** to get all data in a section contained on the `<div class = border fontcontentdet>`.

from selenium import webdriver

```
MAX_PAGE_NUM = 10

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\LVARGAS\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\Scripts\\chromedriver.exe')

data_list = list()

# The for loop is to get each of the 10 pages
for i in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM):
    page_num = str(i)
    url = "https://www.oilandgasnewsworldwide.com/Directory1/DREQ/Drilling_Equipment_Suppliers_?page=" + page_num
    driver.get(url)

    rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='border fontcontentdet']")

    for i in range(0, len(rows)):

        print(rows[i].text)

        data_list.append(rows[i].text)

        print('---')

driver.close()
print(data_list)
```

Comment: thanks, it works. but can you  tell me the reason, i think it because you add the function:    for i in range(1, len(websites)):
                                websites_list.append(websites[i].text) and other two items.why?

Comment: I added some comments into the script. I hope it helps you what is doing each instruction. driver.find_elements helps you to get all the WebElements that you are looking for on each page. I copy the same XPath that you was using. I just edited them a little bit. When you have the WebElements of one page into a list, you cannot get the value at the same time. For this reason I use the loop For i in range (1, len(names)). Here, the i gives us a number that is used to get each one from the list names[i]. Then with .text you get the value of each WebElement, which is added into a new list.

Comment: Actually, there was a little bit mistake. Because the instructions range(1, len(names)) starts to interact with the list from 1, but the first element is 0. So, the correct instruction is range(0, len(names) ). I changed them into the code.

Comment: thank you very much for you detail instruction,Sir.it is very helpful.but i still have a little bit trouble, it is that the name are not corresponding to the right country and website. that is because some name there is no website or country mark.so after we grab the results and put it in a table, you will find all are chaos, so Can you help to avoid it.

Comment: I added an option to get all the information from each element on the directory. You get a list which you can manipulate as you want.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it has something to do with the weird thing you're doing in the page_num assignment.  To debug, try adding this line after you call driver.get(url):

```
print(driver.current_url)
```

If it returns that URLs you are expecting, then most likely the problem is in your XPATH.